# Randomly changing matrix entries

Tags: matrix, replacement, rule

> 1. Write a block of code that generates a 4x4 matrix with randomized real number entries each between 0 & 1, then selects 3 matrix entries
>      at random, and finally replaces these 3 entries with a "nan" string.
> 2. Next, create a function to replace each "nan" in the matrix you just generated with the mean of the numbers that appear in that
>      column.  Note that you are safe in assuming that each column contains
>      at least one real number. **Throughout this problem, use list
>      manipulations, patterns, and rules, but *not* loops.**

Here is what I did for part (1):

```
 mat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 4}]

newMat = mat /. {mat[[RandomInteger[{1, 4}]]][[RandomInteger[{1, 
     4}]]] -> "nan", 
mat[[RandomInteger[{1, 4}]]][[RandomInteger[{1, 4}]]] -> "nan", 
mat[[RandomInteger[{1, 4}]]][[RandomInteger[{1, 4}]]] -> "nan"}
```

But the problem with this is that sometimes, we may choose the same matrix entry twice, resulting in a matrix with only 2 or possibly 1 deleted element! This obviously doesn't work then.

I was thinking of flattening the matrix and then somehow picking out three distinct elements in this list and then replacing them with `"nan"`. How do I randomly pick three things so that hey are distinct and then replace them with `"nan"`? From there I would just repartition the list.

For part (2), I'm really stuck. I know I'll have to transpose the matrix and then take the mean of each list, but the problem with that is: how do I take the mean of a list with an `"nan"` string in it? How do I disregard the string in the list? I also don't know how I can do this without flattening the whole matrix out, thus losing the data for each column.

I was thinking about doing using `Cases` within `Cases`. Is that a good start?

Comment: RandomSample. DeleteCases.

Comment: Something like this? `flatMat = Flatten[mat]` then
`flatMat /. {RandomSample[flatMat, 3] -> {"nan", "nan", "nan"}}`

Comment: `list = RandomSample[flatMat, 3];` and `Partition[
 flatMat /. {x_ /; x === list[[1]] -> "nan", 
   x_ /; x === list[[2]] -> "nan", x_ /; x === list[[3]] -> "nan"}, 4]` solves part 1. Thanks. Now on to part (2)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply consider `Mean` as `Total` of real values divided by the number of real values:

```
n = {4, 4};
k = 3;
mat = RandomReal[1, n];
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
newMat = ReplacePart[mat, RandomSample[Tuples@Range@n, k] -> "nan"];
newMat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Total[newMat /. "nan" -> 0]/Total@Replace[newMat, {"nan" -> 0, _ -> 1}, {2}]
(* {0.647029, 0.723874, 0.421168, 0.693475} *)
```

Comment: That doesn't give the mean of the remaining column entries. It gives the mean of the column where `"nan"` = 0. In other words, it looks like it's taken the mean of four entries.

Comment: @LonelyMathematician I divide by the number of not-"nan" elements so it is the mean of not-"nan" elements.

Comment: (0.313636+0.907441+0.141872)/3 = 0.45431633333 != 0.340737 but (0.313636+0.907441+0.141872)/4 = 0.34073725. Looks to me like you still divided it by four, even though there are three elements in that column, since we don't count the "nan" entry.

Comment: @LonelyMathematician Sorry, I made a mistake in level specification in `Replace`. Now it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 4;
m = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];

Dynamic@TableForm@m
```

[image]

```
Do[
 m = Partition[#, n] & @ ReplacePart[Flatten[m], 
                                     Thread[RandomSample[Range[n^2], n - 1] -> "NAN"]];
 Pause@.1;

 m = Composition[
    Transpose,
    # /. col : {___, "NAN", ___} :> (col /. "NAN" :> Mean[DeleteCases[col, "NAN"]]) &,
    Transpose
    ]@m;

 Pause@.1
 ,
 {15}]
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow this at all. I think you've created a matrix and you proceed to replace n-1 elements? with `"NAN"` which is great and you then find the mean of each column having deleted cases with "NAN". But the problem is you're using a `Do` loop (which I can't use) and the code doesn't actually output anything. This gives me some good ideas but the actual answer isn't very descriptive.

Comment: @LonelyMathematician `Do` is only in order to repeate it. Single procedure have no loops. p.s. you can see what is happening if you evaluate `Dynamic....` from the first code block.

Comment: OH I'm so sorry! I deleted the `Dynamic` part! I'm really sorry about that. I'll take a look tomorrow; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[42];
mat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 4}];
pos = RandomSample[Join @@ MapIndexed[#2 &, mat, {2}], 3];
(* {{3, 4}, {4, 2}, {1, 4}} *)

mat2 = MapAt["nan" &, mat, pos];
mat3 = ReplacePart[mat, pos -> "nan"];
mat4 = mat; (mat4[[##]] = "nan") & @@ # & /@ pos;

Equal @@ {mat2, mat3, mat4}
(* True *)

mat2b = Transpose[Replace[Transpose@mat2, {v__} /; ! FreeQ[{v}, "nan"] :>
            ({v} /. "nan" -> (Total[#]/Length[#] &[DeleteCases[{v}, "nan"]])), 2]];

TableForm[MatrixForm /@ (MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, #, pos] & /@ {mat, mat2, mat2b}),
         TableHeadings -> {{"mat", "mat2", "mat2b"}, None}, TableSpacing -> 5]
```

[image]